# using aggregate modules export - You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm getting an error when exporting a module and using an alias for it.

Upon checking the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), it seems that it's fine to use an alias when exporting a module.

Can you guys help me point out what's wrong this? TIA!

**Code - index.ts**

```
export * from './dummyData';
export * from './interface';
export * as Styled from './styled'; // this line seems to cause the error.
```

**Code - styled.ts**

```
export const Header = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid ${colors.grey450};
`;

export const IconWrapper = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
....
```

**Error**

```
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export * from './dummyData';
| export * from './interface';
> export * as Styled from './styled';
```

Comment: Can you share some details about `styled` file.

Comment: @HarshMangalam  it;s just a regular styled component styles. i've updated my post. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Babel and Webpack?

Comment: @code yes im using both, like a typical CRA

Comment: Your file name is `styled` and you have also imported  with same name `styled` I think you can check there at once and rename the filename.

Comment: @HarshMangalam this one is export, it's supposed to be an aggregate export.

Comment: What is the name of the library for css-in-js?

Comment: @VadimP. it's [styled-component](https://styled-components.com/)

Comment: @Wreeecks Kind of weird. I just installed a fresh version of CRA and styled-component and everything works fine without any additional webpack tweaks. Did you change webpack settings? What versions are you using?